# In Azure DevOps, is there any way to create a permalink to the latest build artifact?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

So I have ADO set up to build my solution whenever I push or merge changes into the master branch, and it generates an artifact, but the path to that artifact changes with every build. Is there any way to create a permalink which always points to the latest build artifact so I can share it with folks without having to either have them click through a bunch of links from the build list or give them a new link every time there is a new build?

To clarify: let's say I have build 1, and the URL is http://azure.com/build/1/artifact or something like that. Now I push some changes and I get build 2 at http://azure.com/build/2/artifact. So I have to update everywhere I'm linking to build 1 to share the app to link to build 2 instead. I'm looking for some sort of http://azure.com/build/latest/artifact which always points to the latest build.

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let us know if you would like further assistance.

Comment: Well, it sounds like it won't be as easy as I hoped! I would like to know if maybe there is a way to get the latest build using JavaScript, so I could attach a script to a hyperlink and have it do all the necessary logic to find and download the build... that would be really nice!

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with JavaScript, so I could not give you a directly solution answer, But the solution is correct, although it doesn't look simple. Because what you need is permalink to the **latest** build artifact, then you can update your question, which you need use JavaScript to achieve your request.

Comment: Yeah, I think permalinking to the latest build artifact would be good enough for starters; I can always provide instructions on what link to click from there to download the binaries... how would I make a permalink to the latest artifact?

Comment: I provided it in my answer, but it is using powershell scripts not JavaScript, if you want to use JavaScript, you may need to convert it by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

https://dev.azure.com/{orgname}/{project}/_apis/build/latest/{pipeline-name}?api-version=5.1-preview.1

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/latest/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1

This will get you the latest build id,

and then, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/artifacts/get%20artifact?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1

With that ID you can then get the artifact.

Comment: Hmm, so I have to call an API just to get the URL to the latest artifact? I tried this link: https://dev.azure.com/edkolis/FrEee/_apis/build/latest/ekolis.FrEee/?api-version=5.1-preview.1 but I get an error `{"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"Folder -1 was not found.","typeName":"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.WebApi.FolderNotFoundException, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build2.WebApi","typeKey":"FolderNotFoundException","errorCode":0,"eventId":3000}`

Comment: Oh hang on, I had an extra slash in that URL. Should be this: https://dev.azure.com/edkolis/FrEee/_apis/build/latest/ekolis.FrEee?api-version=5.1-preview.1 - that gives me some JSON which I guess I'll need to parse...

Comment: Yea, there's no direct way to get the latest artifact. You need the build I'd. An alternative is to upload the artifact to nexus or docker registry, and u can get latest via them

Answer (score 1):

> In Azure DevOps, is there any way to create a permalink to the latest build artifact?

I am afraid there is no such directly way to create a permalink to the latest build artifact.

**That because** the link of the latest build artifact is related to the **build ID**, like:

```
https://dev.azure.com/<OrganizationName>/<ProjectID>/_apis/build/builds/2037/artifacts?artifactName=Test&api-version=5.0&%24format=zip
```

So, the link of the latest build artifact is different based on each build id.

As workaround, we could use REST API [Latest - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/latest/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) to get the latest build for a definition:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/latest/{definition}?api-version=5.1-preview.1
```

The powershell scripts to invoke above API:

```
$url = "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/latest/51?&api-version=5.0-preview.1"
$buildPipeline= Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{   
 Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"
} -Method Get

$BuildId= $buildPipeline.id

Write-Host This is start time: $BuildId
```

Then we could get the latest build of a definition:

[image]

Next, we need to transfer this latest build id to the next REST API [Artifacts - Get Artifact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/artifacts/get%20artifact?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1):

```
Write-Host ("##vso[task.setvariable variable=LatestBuildId]$BuildId")

GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}/artifacts?artifactName={artifactName}&api-version=5.1
```

The powershell scripts:

```
$url = "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/$(LatestBuildId)/artifacts?artifactName=test&api-version=5.0"
$buildPipeline= Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{   
 Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"
} -Method Get

$ArtifactDownloadURL= $buildPipeline.resource.downloadUrl


Write-Host This is start time: $ArtifactDownloadURL
```

The result:

[image]

Now, we could get the link to the latest build artifact.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

While as others have explained, there is no mechanism to currently go directly to the artifacts page for the latest build, you can at least get to the build detail page via a URL of the form:

```
https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{proj}/_build/latest?definitionId={definitionId}
```

where {definitionId} can be found by looking at the URL of your pipeline.